# Live Refresh for multiple Tags in one Tab

Tags: support, tags, live-refresh

I like the *live refresh* of tags. Currently I open for every tag I want to watch a seperate tab in the browser. Why can't I just view all desired tags in one tab?

I tried this in the search box

```
[mysql] [sql] [sql-server]
```

but no questions get added to the list.

Answer (score 4):

#### It does work.

But the search you used only displays questions having **all** of these tags. Use

```
[mysql] OR [sql] OR [sql-server]
```

You can also use wildcards like this

```
[*sql*]
```

to [watch **all** tags containing *SQL*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+or+sql+or+sql-server+or+sql-server-2008+or+sqlite+or+tsql+or+postgresql+or+sql-server-2005+or+linq-to-sql+or+plsql+or+sqlite3+or+mysqli+or+sql-server-2008-r2+or+nosql+or+sqlalchemy+or+sql-update+or+sql-server-ce+or+sql-order-by+or+sql-server-2000+or+sql-server-2012) in it.

Comment: Worth to mention you should be in the *active* tab otherwise no live refresh for you.

Comment: It works for *newest questions* also. I always thought it doesn't. Or this is new.

Comment: Might be a bug!

Comment: *It's not a bug, it's a feature!*